# When drive mapped on a windows machine from remotely by using “net use” command, shows unavailable status

Tags: windows, command-line

I am trying to map a share directory on remote windows machine by executing "net use" command with admin credentials, however the directory is getting mapped and showing status as unavailable. Following is the command I am using, net use * \xx.xxx.x.xx\share\Software /USER:Administrator password

Also I tried the work-arounds like creating a DWORD to "EnableLinkedConnections", and rebooted the system, but still facing the same issue.

Comment: According to [Net use](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx) `password` should come **before** `/user`.

Comment: I have already tried to have password before /user, it doesn't resolve the issue I am facing,